# Copyright page on back of title page

Tags: page-breaking, titles, front-matter

I am trying to get the copyright page to print (or display) on the back of the title page. What is happening is that I get a blank page after the title page and then the copyright page opens on the right hand side. What I would like to do is eliminate the blank page immediately after the title page and have the copyright page print on the back of the title page.

I am using the `memoir` class (though Koma-script `scrbook` has the same behavior). Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bottom=1in}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\begin{center}
\huge{Los picapiedras}

\vspace{1 in}
\bigskip
f.flinstone
\end{center}
\end{titlingpage}

\frontmatter
\textit{Picapiedras}
here is the copyright page

\mainmatter

\lettrine{Y}{o estaba alojado} en un hotel 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please check http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12574/963

Answer (score 10):

You can locally stop `\cleardoublepage` making the blank page:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bottom=1in}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\begin{center}
\huge{Los picapiedras}

\vspace{1 in}
\bigskip
f.flinstone
\end{center}
\end{titlingpage}


\begin{titlingpage}
\textit{Picapiedras}
here is the copyright page
\end{titlingpage}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\lettrine{Y}{o estaba alojado} en un hotel 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use a `\clearpage` inside the `titlingpage` environment to have a new page for the copyright information:

```
\begin{titlingpage}
\begin{center}
\huge{Los picapiedras}

\vspace{1in}
\bigskip
f.flinstone
\end{center}\clearpage
\textit{Picapiedras}
here is the copyright page
\end{titlingpage}
```

However, the `memoir` documentation suggests not using the `titlingpage` environment:

> However, I suggest that you ignore the `titlingpage` environment and
>   just use regular LaTeX typesetting without any special environment.

So, you can simply say something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bottom=1in}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\huge{Los picapiedras}

\vspace{1in}
f.flinstone
\end{center}
\clearpage
\textit{Picapiedras}
here is the copyright page
\clearpage

\frontmatter

\pagestyle{plain}
\mainmatter

\lettrine{Y}{o estaba alojado} en un hotel 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, I cannot find the suggestion not to use the `titlingpage` environment in the `memoir` documentation that @gonzalo-medina mentions in his answer.

What the docs now say is:

> At the end of a `titlingpage` clearing code is issued, which can send you to
>   the next page or the next right handed page. Using `\titlingpageend{⟨twoside code⟩}{⟨oneside code⟩}`, you can specify what this clearing code should be. The default
>   is `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage` respectively.

In your case you could use:

```
\begin{titlingpage}
    ...
    \titlingpageend{\clearpage}{\clearpage}
\end{titlingpage}
```

This way, the copyright info can be outside the `titlingpage` environment and still print on the back of the title page (verso).

Comment: In this way, the counting of the page will be incorrect, resulting a blank page between the `titleback` page and the next section...