# How to insert copyright line on Title Page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, copyright

I am new to LaTeX.   would like to insert the copyright on the title page of my ebook. This is what I want it to look like (centered in the middle of the page):

```
Title,
Author,
Copyright (copyright symbol) 2013 by Author,
All Rights Rserved,
eISBN:
```

Below is what I have tried so far. However, I continue to get an error for the copyright line. I chose `report` because it was closer to an ebook format.
After trying to read through some LaTeX "basics" this is what I came up with.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\title{ebook title here}
\author{my name}
\Copyright \copyright\; 2013 my name\\
All Rights Reserved\\ 
\maketitlepage
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/how-to-add-a-copyright-page-to-the-report-class

Answer (score 5):

You probably do not need a date in your book, so why not:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\title{ebook title here}
\author{my name}
\date{\copyright\ 2013 my name\\
All Rights Reserved} 

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]